# Phrase required for "Defeated person is more dangerous"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In my native language there exists a phrase **Injured snake** 
A wounded snake is assumed to be more vigorous/dangerous.

Are there any similar phrase/idiom/proverb in English?

Answer (score 3):

The phrase ***like a cornered rat*** has a similar meaning, though the rat is trapped rather than injured, the idea that a desperate animal is particularly dangerous still applies.

Comment: Can you please provide some links to the sources?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q="a+cornered+rat"+-skyrim+-dictionary

Comment: thanks for the link. Is this commonly used in US/UK?

Comment: I believe so, most of the links are from the US and the UK - but I'm in Australia.

Comment: TBH this phrase is excellent. However, I couldn't find any references in _thefreedictionary.com_ or in any online dictionaries.   Is this commonly used in Australia?

Comment: I think people generally know what it means. Now I think of it, in Australia we also have a phrase "mad as a cut snake".

Comment: In the US, the phrase "a cornered rat" (or "a trapped rat") would be universally recognized.

Comment: @Malvolio Why there is no online references?

Comment: @dynamite -- would [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107419/is-there-an-idiom-beginning-when-a-dog-is-cornered) count as a reference?

Comment: @Malvolio A pure English proverb/idiom would be of great help.

Comment: @dynamite, what do you mean by a ‘pure English’ proverb/idiom? “Like a cornered rat” is widely used both in American, British, Australian, Irish, and probably most other types of English. The fact that dictionaries don’t seem to have included it as a set phrase doesn’t mean it isn’t one.

Comment: As for sources, [A Dictionary of American Proverbs (p. 65)](http://books.google.dk/books?id=AbJ1tVGmiTgC&lpg=RA1-PA65&ots=1FGAc31m2z&dq&pg=RA1-PA65) does have the expression.

Answer (score 1):

**"like a wounded animal"** is quite common actually. Usually used in sports when a defeated team strikes back like a wounded animal.

**Examples:**

> Tom Watson's United States team will go into the 2014 Ryder Cup in Scotland **"like a wounded animal" after snatching defeat from the jaws of victory** in Illinois two years ago, said Europe captain Paul McGinley. 
>   <sub>Source: http://ca.reuters.com/article/sportsNews/idCABREA251Z520140306</sub>

---

> “At London Irish we lost ten games in all competitions but **a desperate team is a dangerous team. It’s like a wounded animal, they’re fighting for their last breath.** 
>   <sub>Source: http://www.bathchronicle.co.uk/Worcester-like-wounded-animal-fighting-breath/story-20973791-detail/story.html</sub>

---

> Emotions have a voice; when they're wounded, they may react like a wounded animal. **Wounded animals can be quite dangerous**, and so can wounded emotions if they're followed. 
>   <sub>Source: http://www.joycemeyer.org/articles/ea.aspx?article=overcoming_grief_and_loneliness</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Don't mess with a wounded bear.](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2519&dat=19810228&id=aPJdAAAAIBAJ&sjid=Xl8NAAAAIBAJ&pg=1078,4989817)

[Don't mess with a wounded tiger.](http://tigerboard.com/boards/missouri-tigers.php?message=7438221)

Other comparators are (a wounded) lion, lioness, wolverine, dog, soldier. *Duck*!?

Answer (score -1):

The idiom **Hell hath no fury like a woman scorned** applies

Comment: Good answer, But too long to be used. Is this archaic?

Comment: It is from The Mourning Bride (1697) William Congreve but common in cultural lingo.  Congreve is also noted for "O fie, miss, you must not kiss and tell." and "Music has charms to soothe a savage breast".  Interestingly, "Hell hath no fury..." is often wrongly ascribed to William Shakespeare

Comment: thanks for the references :) A commonly used phrase will be of great help.

Comment: I should tell you it is used humorously too.

Comment: @ThirdNews -- I believe there is a name for the phenomenon whereby any witty or wise expression becomes attributed to a much better known person than the actual author.  There's a quotation floating around the Internet ascribed to the Buddha that is in fact from an early-90s self-help book.  Congreve/Shakespeare confusion is at least _plausible_.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering if pseudepigraphy applies to quotes